# CakePHP 2.5 JQuery Ajax Login Element

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp-2.0

Okay, so I must of missed something key or basic.  I'm trying to create a Login Element that uses JQuery/AJAX to login.

On my layout I have:

```
    //...
    echo $this->Html->script('jquery'); // Include jQuery library
    //...
    if (AuthComponent::user('id')){ 
        echo $this->element('userElement',array('username'=>AuthComponent::user('username')));
    } else {
        echo $this->element('loginElement');
    }
    echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();
```

UserElement simply says "Hi $username" and works fine when I manually login by going to /users/login/

Here is loginElement.ctp, where I think the problem is:

```
<?php
    $data = $this->Js->get('#UserForm')->serializeForm(array('isForm' => true, 'inline' => true));
    $this->Js->get('#UserForm')->event(
        'submit',
        $this->Js->request(
            array('action' => 'save'),
                array(
                    'update' => '#loadingdiv',//what to update while ajaxing
                    'before' => "$('#loading').fadeIn();",//before request
                    'complete' => "$('#loading').fadeOut();",//when request complete
                    'data' => $data,
                    'async' => true,    
                    'dataExpression'=>true,
                    'method' => 'POST',
                 )
            )
        );
?>
<div class="loadingdiv" id="loadingdiv"> </div>
<div class="users form">
    <?php
        echo $this->Session->flash('auth');
        echo $this->Form->create('User',array('action' => 'save', 'default' =>     false));
    ?>
    <fieldset>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('username');
        echo $this->Form->input('password');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->end(__('Login'));
        echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();
    ?>
</div>
```

The form doesn't do anything, no login, no failed javascript call in the browser console....nothing.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'm answering my own question so that if anyone else stumbled upon this problem they can see what was wrong and how to fix it:

The two key pieces here are:

```
//create the form
echo $this->Form->create('User',array('action' => 'save', 'default' =>     false));
```

and

```
//bind the event
$this->Js->get('#UserForm')->event(
//...
```

I'm binding the event to the form "UserForm", but when I create the form I'm giving it an action of "save" .. so the form name that cake automatically build is "UserSaveForm"

When I changed the binding to "UserSaveForm" it worked.

[Note after fixing this 'save' looked weird so I changed the form action, binding and controller function to 'login'  so I ended up with the form "UserLoginForm" which reads much better]